# How to get expected json value in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am making a json after watching a json object ,But I am getting more key or text .I need to remove that text.

I am getting this output

```
function mapItem(inputItem) {
    var item = {};
    item[inputItem.id] = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.id));

    for (k in inputItem.children) {
        if (/^not-/.test(inputItem.children[k].id)) {
            item[inputItem.id].commandList.push(mapItem(inputItem.children[k]));
        }else{
            item[inputItem.id].testCaseList.push(mapItem(inputItem.children[k]));  
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Kq/7/
I THINK PROBLEM ON THIS LINE

```
            item[inputItem.id].commandList.push(mapItem(inputItem.children[k]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

http://jsfiddle.net/tJ7Kq/8/

```
function mapItem(inputItem) {
    //var item = {};
    var item = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(inputItem.id));

    for (k in inputItem.children) {
        if (/^not-/.test(inputItem.children[k].id)) {
            item.commandList.push(mapItem(inputItem.children[k]));
        }else{
            item.testCaseList.push(mapItem(inputItem.children[k]));  
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```